# Is there way in R fold increase/decrease between all rows of one dataframe with all rows of another dataframe, and create a new df depicting that?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have two dataframes with different rows. I want to construct a new dataframe by pairwise comparison of each of first dataframe to each row of second dataframe. The new dataframe depicts fold increase or decrease in count between every row of both dataframes.

The two dataframes are:

```
#First dataframe
structure(list(Label = c("Gene 1", "Gene 2", "Gene 3", "Gene 4", 
"Gene 5", "Gene 6", "Gene 7", "Gene 8", "Gene 9", "Gene 10", 
"Gene 11", "Gene 12", "Gene 13", "Gene 14", "Gene 15", "Gene 16", 
"Gene 17", "Gene 18", "Gene 19", "Gene 20", "Gene 21", "Gene 22", 
"Gene 23", "Gene 24", "Gene 25", "Gene 26", "Gene 27", "Gene 28", 
"Gene 29", "Gene 30"), Count = c(1500, 1600, 1700, 1800, 1900, 
2000, 2100, 2200, 2300, 2400, 2500, 2600, 2700, 2800, 2900, 3000, 
3100, 3200, 3300, 3400, 3500, 3600, 3700, 3800, 3900, 4000, 4100, 
4200, 4300, 4400)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-30L))


#Second dataframe
structure(list(Label = c("Control1", "Control2", "Control3", 
"Control4", "Control5", "Control6", "Control7", "Control8", "Control9", 
"Control10", "Control11", "Control12", "Control13", "Control14", 
"Control15", "Control16", "Control17", "Control18", "Control19", 
"Control20", "Control21", "Control22", "Control23", "Control24"
), Count = c(1800, 1400, 1110, 1900, 2500, 2900, 2100, 900, 5000, 
2300, 700, 1400, 3400, 2310, 3322, 2200, 4400, 2100, 1000, 6700, 
4300, 2120, 4800, 4300)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -24L))
```

My output should look something like this [desired output (here its just an example)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxqPx.png)

Is there any function that does this or looping is the only option? Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `tidyverse` approach here (naming the first data.frame `df1`, the second one `df2`):

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
  full_join(df2, by = character(0), suffix = c("", ".y")) %>% 
  mutate(value = Count.y / Count, .keep = "unused") %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "Label.y")
```

This returns

```r
# A tibble: 30 × 25
   Label   Control1 Control2 Control3 Control4 Control5 Contr…¹ Contr…² Contr…³ Contr…⁴ Contr…⁵ Contr…⁶
   <chr>      <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 Gene 1     1.2      0.933    0.74     1.27      1.67    1.93   1.4     0.6      3.33   1.53    0.467
 2 Gene 2     1.12     0.875    0.694    1.19      1.56    1.81   1.31    0.562    3.12   1.44    0.438
 3 Gene 3     1.06     0.824    0.653    1.12      1.47    1.71   1.24    0.529    2.94   1.35    0.412
 4 Gene 4     1        0.778    0.617    1.06      1.39    1.61   1.17    0.5      2.78   1.28    0.389
 5 Gene 5     0.947    0.737    0.584    1         1.32    1.53   1.11    0.474    2.63   1.21    0.368
 6 Gene 6     0.9      0.7      0.555    0.95      1.25    1.45   1.05    0.45     2.5    1.15    0.35 
 7 Gene 7     0.857    0.667    0.529    0.905     1.19    1.38   1       0.429    2.38   1.10    0.333
 8 Gene 8     0.818    0.636    0.505    0.864     1.14    1.32   0.955   0.409    2.27   1.05    0.318
 9 Gene 9     0.783    0.609    0.483    0.826     1.09    1.26   0.913   0.391    2.17   1       0.304
10 Gene 10    0.75     0.583    0.462    0.792     1.04    1.21   0.875   0.375    2.08   0.958   0.292
# … with 20 more rows, 13 more variables: Control12 <dbl>, Control13 <dbl>, Control14 <dbl>,
#   Control15 <dbl>, Control16 <dbl>, Control17 <dbl>, Control18 <dbl>, Control19 <dbl>,
#   Control20 <dbl>, Control21 <dbl>, Control22 <dbl>, Control23 <dbl>, Control24 <dbl>, and
#   abbreviated variable names ¹​Control6, ²​Control7, ³​Control8, ⁴​Control9, ⁵​Control10, ⁶​Control11
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows, and `colnames()` to see all variable names
```

Comment: Marrrtiiiin, so glad to see you :)

Comment: Hey @AnoushiravanR :) Hope you're doing well.